Does Possess Object have the size limitation?
Posses Object is a spell that shares some features with both Magic Jar and Animate Objects and is written very strangely.
https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Possess%20Object
Key parts being:

This spell functions as magic jar...

...and...

...animating it as if using animate objects...

...it doesn't specify which parts of Animate Objects it inherits though, if any. The way it is written I should be able to possess any object in detection range of gem, regardless of size. One of my co-players suggested it might inherit Animate Objects size limitation though, which I don't believe it does. After all "spell functions as" refers to entire spell, while "animating as if using" refers just to the process of animating, not the entire spell description and it's targeting criteria (and this line of text happens after targeting is already done).
Which interpretation is correct by RAW?

There is no rule that limits size, but your GM should
The entire effect text of Possess Object is

This spell functions as magic jar, except you transfer your mind to a single object, animating it as if using animate objects, except your mind controls the object as if it were your own body. You cannot speak or cast spells while possessing the object. Because your original body is effectively dead while under the effect of this spell, this temporarily suspends disease, poisons, and other afflictions affecting you.

The Possess Object spell itself does not impose a size limitation on the single object it targets. The Animate Objects spell normally animates objects as follows

Targets one Small object per caster level; see text
You may animate one Small or smaller object or a corresponding number of larger objects as follows: A Medium object counts as two Small or smaller objects, a Large object as four, a Huge object as eight, a Gargantuan object as 16, and a Colossal object as 32.

These rules make no sense in the context of Possess Object. The text that limits size is tied into the targeting by reference, so it is part of targeting. However, Possess Object can only animate a single object of unspecified size, not a number of objects, and therefore, we can conclude it is using its own targeting rules. Otherwise you should be able to possess multiple objects. Hence, you can animate an object of any size, rules as written.
Your GM might want to impose some sanity check for balance reasons, because normally at spell level 6 the caster may be as low as 11th caster level, and would not be able to animate a gargantuan or colossal object, and at spell level 5 that Posses Object has, they could be as low as caster level 9, and would barely be able to animate a huge object.
